# MarkLogic function to disable Scheduled Task

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there a MarkLogic built-in function to disable a group scheduled task?

Before I knew such function already exists, I created my own -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()

let $existingConfig := admin:group-get-scheduled-tasks($config, admin:group-get-id($config, "Default"))/fn:root()

let $newConfig := element configuration { mem:node-replace($existingConfig//*:scheduled-task/*:task-enabled/text(), text{"false"})!mem:node-delete(./*:groups/@timestamp) }

return admin:save-configuration($newConfig)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [`admin:group-scheduled-task-set-enabled()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-scheduled-task-set-enabled). Don't forget to apply config changes using [`admin:save-configuration()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:save-configuration).

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @grtjn. My bad, I missed this function.